# React Context Rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am new to React and i am very confused about how Context API works in React. I would like to explain my confusion giving a example.

I have 3 child components:

A component:

```
function A() {
  const { setC } = useContext(context);

  console.log("A rendered");

  return (
    <div
      onClick={(e) => {
        setC((prev) => prev + 1);
      }}
    >
      A
    </div>
  );
}
```

B component:

```
function B() {
  const { B } = useContext(context);
  console.log("B rendered");

  return <div>{B}</div>;
}
```

C component:

```
function C() {
  const { C } = useContext(context);

  console.log("C rendered");

  return <div>{C}</div>;
}
```

And there is a Context component which is wrap everything:

```
const context = createContext();

function Cont({ children }) {
  const [A, setA] = useState(0);
  const [B, setB] = useState(10);
  const [C, setC] = useState(20);

  return (
    <context.Provider value={{ A, setA, B, setB, C, setC }}>
      {children}
    </context.Provider>
  );
}

export { Cont, context };
```

And this is the App component:

```
import "./App.css";
import A from "./components/A";
import B from "./components/B";
import C from "./components/C";
import { Cont } from "./components/Cont";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Cont>
        <A></A>
        <B></B>
        <C></C>
      </Cont>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you can see in the component A i set the state of C by incrementing one. My confusion is when i setting C state all of the child re-renders for example i setting C in A but i do not change the value of B but B component still re-renders.Additionally Content of A does not change and A component re-renders too. Is there any way to prevent this or is it the nature of Context API. Any help will be appriciated. Thanks.

I tried to use memo as i researched but i think it is only works in components which is not using useContext and this is make  me confused

Comment: Yes, if context's value changes all components that use this context will rerender

Comment: You can still also use memoization to solve this. It's right that its unavoidable that the component with `useContext` rerenders. However, you can make that component very cheap by doing nothing more than pass down to a component that is memoized. However, you really do not need to care about this unless you have a perf problem to solve. "I want to reduce rerenders" without having an actual perf problem is a common "optimizing too early" pitall beginners sometimes fall into. Memoization is not free and is a maintenance burden and also has its own computational cost.

Comment: @adsy Sir you mentioned there is a way. Would you like to give me an example. Thank you for your answer,sir.

Comment: Have a look at https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-optimize-your-context-value